# Getting google drive list / files from own account without manual authorization

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm creating an app for android and would like to show some pictures to my users. Pictures may change in number and names so I want to be able to get a listing of the files and the file content but without authorizing the user/app. I have been playing with this a bit without any luck. Is there any way to do this making the folder public or something?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder is not public, there is no way you can view it or list it without authorizing. This is the whole purpose of the permission system.

Authorization on Android is pretty easy though, please check the [Android quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) for more details.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do this having all files being public? I have been checking the api and seems that it is not possible either

Comment: You can use site publishing in that case, and just fetch the file with plain https calls. https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site